# urllib2 on ubuntu installation is urlencoding data

Tags: python, urllib2

These are the exact lines I have run with a lot of success in the past. It has worked always

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
>>> url = 'http://************************/login' #not the exact URL
>>> r = urllib2.Request(url, headers)
>>> d = '{"username":"ranjith", "password":"ranjith"}'
>>> urllib2.urlopen(r, d).read()
```

But on a specific ubuntu machine in the office, the above lines are not working as expected. The issue seems to be that the data that has been sent to the server is urlencoded, which is very unexpected. Upon printing the request_body on the server, the log usually looks like

```
request.body:{"username":"ranjith", "password":"ranjith"}
```

but when the request is made from this specific computer it looks like

```
request.body:%7B%22username%22%3A%22ranjith%22%2C+%22password%22%3A%22ranjith%22%7D=
```

This is bizarre to say the least. What could be the reason for this?

I spent a lot of time debugging this, including doing an altinstall of python from source into this computer. I am not able to say at which layer this is happening either. Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Specific question (in case someone in stackoverflow decides this question is not asking anything specific):

How to prevent the urllib2 on a computer in my office from urlencoding request body data?

Python version is 2.7.6 everywhere

Comment: Is the Python version on this particular system different from what you're using elsewhere?  Which version is installed?

Comment: It is python2.7 everywhere